# Other than sql which database we can use in android?

Tags: android

> Is there any Database such as DB2,...,etc are available to use in android than that of SQLite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of databases such as :

- XAMP
- SQLite SQLite is a widely used database for android.Its very lightweight one      and easy to use.And it is the one which has default support by android.
- SQL
- Firebase Realtime Database
- Realm
- and many other databases

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL provided on XAMPP or WAMP if you want a local hosting.  SQLite is enough for basic outline. MySQL is more than enough to get the whole structure of modelling.